# Rails — Formtastic, how to set text for options in select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

```
f.input :some_model_values, :as => :select
```

Using Formtastic, I need to set a text for options on my select input, but not populated from :some_model_values.

The second:
how could be collection of :some_model_values pre-modefied? Because i don want to show some options according to user role.

Thanks!

Comment: f.input :some_model_values, :as => :select, :collection => @user.some_options

#/app/models/user.rb
def some_options
  #should return an array of options
end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do You mean with "set a text for option on my select input" ?

Please have a look at the :collection parameter, for example:

```
f.input :some_model_values, :as => :select, :collection => [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
f.input :some_model_values, :as => :select, :collection => [["male",1], ["female",2], ["other",3]]
```

When you want to set the label, the best option is to localise it by the /config/locales/#locale#.rb file

Hope this helps

Comment: I was looking for this thanks! And nice response, quite complete! You even taken into account the "other" gender. Developers should be careful with this kind of stuff, never to hurt people's feelings =)